# need clue for "exit code 40"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I ran a self-developed ros node via roslaunch, it could run for some time, e.g., 10 mins, and then reports the following error and quit:

"[dm-1] process has died [pid 4365, exit code 40].
log files: /home/robot/.ros/log/0119ddc6-2ad9-11e1-be05-000df06e274c/dm-1*.log"

I couldn't find any info about the exit code 40, so any help will be welcome and appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12406/need-clue-for-%22exit-code-40%22/) by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 393 on 2011-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's weired, the same code runs without crash on another computer.
What could be the reason to cause the program terminatation, which is specific to the first computer?

---

Originally posted by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) with karma: 393 on 2011-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try following [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) tutorial to run your code in a debugger. This will give you more information regarding the error. You should also check your log files.

If your code runs for 10 minutes and then dies, my first guess would be a memory leak that's causing an overflow.

**EDIT**: This probably won't solve your problem, but is there any condition in your `main()` in which you return 050? According to gdb, that's the return code being received from the `main()`. Perhaps you don't have a return statement in `main()`?

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1